# Cube in Spherical Coordinates not centred at the origin

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates

I`ve seen that there are already a couple of questions about how to describe a cube in Spherical Coordinates. However they are all centred at the origin.

I would like to describe a cube in Spherical Coordinates which has vertices in $(0; 0; 0), (0; 1; 0), (1; 0; 0), (1; 1; 0), (0; 0; 1),
(0; 1; 1), (1; 0; 1)$ and $(1; 1; 1)$. So basically is a cube in the first quadrant with four vertices on the three axes.

My idea was first of all starting by describing a square in spherical coordinates, so that I can use what I find to describe the cube more easily. The square that I take is the base of this cube, i.e. $(0; 0; 0), (0; 1; 0), (1; 0; 0), (1; 1; 0)$. This is what I got, by simple geometry: (Where $\theta$ is the angle with the $x$ axis and $r$ is the length of the radius.)
$\{(r,\theta) : 0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4} , 0\leq r\leq sec(\theta)\}\cup\{(r,\theta) :\frac{\pi}{4}<\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}, 0\leq r\leq cosec(\theta)\}$
Now I was trying to develop this into the $xyz$ plane, using $\rho$ as $\rho^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $\phi$ as the angle between the $z$ axis and $\rho$. However it gets very complicated and even if I literally built a huge paper cube to be able to visualize better the situation, I don`t understand how to describe it.

I was thinking of dividing the whole thing mainly in two big cases:

1. When $0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{4}$
2. When $\frac{\pi}{4}< \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

So in the first one we have some subcases:

1. When $\theta=0$ then we basically have the situation of the square, just in the $zx$ plane instead on the $xy$ plane
2. When $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ then is similar to the situation of the square, however now we have a rectangle, where one side is $1$ and the other is $\sqrt{2}$. However using similar arguments that those used for the square, I found out that we basically get almost the same by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, i.e. $\{(\rho,\phi) : 0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{4} , 0\leq \rho\leq \sqrt{2}sec(\theta)\}\cup\{(\rho,\phi) :\frac{\pi}{4}<\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}, 0\leq \rho\leq \sqrt{2}cosec(\theta)\}$.

   3. When $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I have no idea on how to go ahead. How should I describe this part?
And after doing this huge part $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$ how should I work to get the other part, i.e. $\frac{\pi}{4}<\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Please help me, I know it is very laborious but I tried to do this all afternoon. There must be a way.

Thanks

Comment: Choosing Spherical, not Cartesian coordinates  is inviting computational trouble.

Comment: yeah I know, but I really want to solve it that way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in spherical coordinates only because you're integrating a spherically-symmetric function, you might reconsider whether Cartesian coordinates are simpler. Or, if you're (say) trying to calculate the flux of a radially-symmetric field through the faces of the cube, Gauss's theorem may obviate the need to describe a cube in spherical coordinates.

That said: There are several conventions for spherical coordinates, but based on your user name I'll assume you're using $\phi$ to denote longitude and $\theta$ to denote colatitude, so that
$$
(x, y, z) = (\rho\cos\phi \sin\theta, \rho\sin\phi \sin\theta, \rho\cos\theta),\qquad 0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi,\quad 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi.
$$

The planes $x = 1$, $y = 1$, and $z = 1$ have respective equations
$$
\rho = \sec\phi \csc\theta,\qquad
\rho = \csc\phi \csc\theta,\qquad
\rho = \sec\theta.
$$
One way to integrate over your cube is $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$, and
$$
0 \leq \rho \leq \min(\sec\phi \csc\theta, \csc\phi \csc\theta, \sec\theta).
$$
The remaining problem is to split up the square in the $(\phi, \theta)$-plane so that the minimum on the right can be replaced, in each of three regions, by *one* of the formulas inside the minimum. This is mildly vexing geometrically, because the edges of the cube in the plane $z = 1$ do not correspond to lines in the $(\phi, \theta)$-plane.

An algebraic argument may work best: The plane $x = z$, for example, has equation $\sec\phi \csc\theta = \sec\theta$, or $\sec\phi = \tan\theta$, or $\theta = \arctan(\sec\phi)$. The integral over the corresponding third of the cube (the pyramid with vertex at the origin and the face $x = 1$ as base) has limits
$$
0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/4,\qquad
\arctan(\sec\phi) \leq \theta \leq \pi/2,\qquad
0 \leq \rho \leq \sec\phi \csc\theta.
$$
The other two pyramids are similar; I leave the pleasure of working out the details to you.

Comment: More careful reading of your post reveals I reversed the roles of $\phi$ and $\theta$ from your notation. Adjust accordingly. :)

Comment: Well my name is such because I study mathematics, but I like physics as well and I learn it in my free-time, also using stack-exchange. Anyway no I was using $\theta$ as the angle in the $x-y$ plane from the positive $x$ axis, counterclock-wise. While $\phi$ is the angle between the $z$ axis and $\rho$. Thanks for your answer tho, I'm gonna read it now.

Comment: Ahaha just read your comment now, great!